# Extract Attachment from Activity in DirectLine Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot that works using built-in channels along with DirectLine for custom channels.

Within the DirectLine channel, I get the response activities and I am trying to extract the information from `Attachments` so that I can convert it into a custom channel format.

While parsing the activities, I check for an attachment, and find it is on `"ContentType" = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero"` I then try to cast the attachment `Content` as a `HeroCard`. This does not work within the DirectLine channel.  Within my unit tests of the builtin channels, I am able to do this, and validate all of my data properly.

Is this not an expected behavior? How can I get the content of the attachment within the DirectLine channel?

```
var type = attachment.ContentType;
if (type == "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero")
{
    var temp = attachment.Content;
    var heroCard = temp as HeroCard; // This yields a 'null'
    ...
}
```

Note: if I replace the line "var heroCard = temp as HeroCard;" with

```
var temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attachment.Content);
var heroCard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HeroCard>(temp);
```

I then have a hero card that i can parse. But this seems very inefficient.

Comment: Hi NiteLordz! Can you clarify what it is you're looking to extract? If you're looking to extract the actual card, like an attachment on an email, that's not possible. Hero Cards, like all rich/adaptive cards, are rendered JSON objects.

Comment: Sure.  I am not trying to render it, I am trying to gain access to the internal members of the card (Title, Subtitle, etc...). Right now, Attachment.Content is an object.  I was hoping I would be able to do a simple cast to "HeroCard", however, that fails.  I am able to take the Object, serialize it to a string and then deserialize it to a Hero Card. At this point I am able to get the title, subtitle, images, etc.. and pass that along to a custom channel implementation.

Answer (score 1):

DirectLine channel means you have to do most of the conversation manually, 
whereas other built in channel, there are connector built in, hence convert is done automatic behind the scene.

you can optimize your current code a little better by without serializing it first, i.e:

```
var heroCard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HeroCard>(attachment.Content.ToString());
```

but other than that, there is no other way I am aware of you can optimize in converting to strong type.